# How to know that a visitor is using a Mobile?

Tags: php, mobile, responsive-design, mobile-website

I designed a theme for mobiles for my website. But I do not know how to "redirect" mobiles visitors to that theme?

What are the available options for my scenario?

Comment: Browser name? Width and height?

Comment: No, I want to detect that a visitor is from a Mobile not a PC.

Comment: @MrLister Identifying a device type by browser width and height is bound to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect and redirect mobile users by using this [PHP class](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `media="handheld"` attribute when you are specifying your CSS file, so that it would only load for handheld devices, such as mobile phones. But this is becoming redundant nowadays, since android browsers and the iPhone's browser do not identify themseleves as `handheld` devices, to prevent from being served webpages with minimal formatting.

Take a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872893/what-parameters-does-the-css-media-type-handheld-care-about)** thread.

To load a custom `phone.css` for a mobile phone, you can rely on the user's screen width and use a `media` query.

For example, add this into your `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="phone.css" />
```

Now, `phone.css` will load when the screen width of the device is less than `480px`.

For a detailed explanation, check out **[this](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)** source.

Hope this helped. `:)`

Comment: I like your answer better than mine. +1.

Comment: Thanks `:)` I am glad you do. The question intrigued me, and I read up on it just now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the [user agent string](http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/WhatsAUserAgent) of the HTTP request.

Based on that, you can redirect to the corresponding site, or load the right CSS/resource files etc.

If you wish to see the user agent string for your browser, you can go to **[this](http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/)** site. For example, I'm using Chrome in a Windows 8 PC right now, and my string is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36

I have a plethora of Android devices at home. When browsing with Chrome, they all have basically the same user agent string. The site I linked to also lists the most common ones (check the links in the footer).